# Issue in calling the OneDrive for Business REST API to upload image files

Tags: rest, api, azure, integration, onedrive

I am facing the issue in calling the OneDrive for Business API to work. Below are the steps I have followed till now:

1. Created a Web App/API application in Microsoft Azure Portal (A very tricky process). Gave all the permissions.
2. Got Application ID (A_ID) from there.
3. Went to the URL to get the 'code' via browser:

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<A_ID>&redirect_uri=<URI>`
4. Got the code. Did a callout via POSTMAN (using the code, client ID, client secret and redirect URI) to the URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`
5. Received an Access Token (AT) and other details.
6. NOW, when I want to use this AT to upload a file, I am getting the error. The URI is: `https://<tenant>/_api/v2.0/me/drive/root:/Abc.txt:/content`. For headers, I am passing: `Authorization-> Bearer AT; Content-Type -> application/octet-stream`

The error is:

`{"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Token contains invalid signature.","innerError":{"code":"invalidSignature"}}}`

I don't know where the issue is. Is it in the tenant name I am using (There is a chance that I might be using it wrong!) OR is it in the permissions OR I have not set up the app in the Azure Portal correctly OR is it something entirely different.

Comment: What was the `resource` you used when acquiring the access token? It seems that it's a bit complicated with this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/aad-oauth. Have you checked Microsoft Graph API? I think it provides a bit easier access to OneDrive for Business. You'll need to add the necessary delegated permission to access user files in MS Graph API and then use `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` in your request to /token to get the access token.

Comment: @juunas For MS Graph API, it says to register an app first at [link](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). Here, I am not able to log in for the OneDrive for Business account. However, I am able to log in and create an app for personal OneDrive via this.
The requirement here is to integrate with OneDrive for Business.

Comment: You can use either that or Azure Portal. That's the new v2 portal. There it depends if you log in with a personal MS account or organization AAD account where the app gets registered. But v2 apps can also use OneDrive for Business via MS Graph API.

Comment: @juunas I am able to generate an access token. The issue is, I am not able to use it. Whenever I do a callout to upload a file, I get the error: `{"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Token contains invalid signature.","innerError":{"code":"invalidSignature"}}}`. 

The URL to which I am making the callout to upload files is: `[tenant]+/_api/v2.0/me/drive/root:/Abc.txt:/content`. Is the URL wrong here???

Comment: Yeah if you use the resource parameter I said, you'll have to use MS Graph API, not onedrive api

Comment: @juunas I am at a loss here. What should be the URL then to upload files? Is it something generic?

Comment: This should help you out: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content :)